# Is relational database the optimal data structure for me?

Tags: database-design, mariadb, relational-database

I am going to be tracking several changing properties on a weekly basis for about 30 million entities. The values of tracked properties are all integers.

I can’t decide on how to store them in the most optimal way. If I create a second one-to-many table, where I enter a row for every property, when it is observed, I’ll create **30 million entities * 52 weeks * number of property entries per year**. The table would get huge, but I would be able to query it for specific periods, compare different periods..

On the other hand, I could put weekly data points in arrays of integers or even stringified objects, where all properties are keys and the tracked integers are values and dedicate 1 row that keeps getting modified to each of my 30 million tracked items. Now I am unable to do complex queries and comparisons directly in DB, but I can still pull the data for specific item and display it. I don’t know yet every comparisons I’ll want to do, but I think I would like to be able to check for biggest gainers or losers at least.

Should I settle for one of these options? Should I pick a different DB structure entirely and why? I am currently using MariaDB. If my example is too contrived, imagine storing stock market data as the closest analogy, where every point in time (tick) has to store several properties for a particular stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is made to handle really vast simple time-series tables with fixed-length columns like

```
id        entity_id   property_id  datestamp    value
BIGINT       INT          INT       DATETIME     appropriate type
```

Anytime an property change shows up in your system, you simply insert a row into that table.

With proper indexing, MySQL or any other RDBMS can handle gigarows of that kind of data without much trouble. Drive space is very cheap, and the server's capacity needs to match the number of programs accessing it, not so much the amount of historical data it contains.  So don't rule out SQL. Your application is in its sweet spot.

And, handling those simple rows with SQL will be much more efficient than the large-object read-modify-write scheme you suggested.  The software will be far simpler to write, test, troubleshoot, and audit. You'll need to do all those things easily if you go into production. They're important when you're handling other peoples' money.

And, the latest versions of MariaDb have a [system versioning feature](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) for tables that's worth investigating.

Comment: Does that mean I will be fine with a table with a few dozen billion rows a few years down the line? I don't need to store data permanently, but a cupule of years is desired.

Comment: It's a good question. The answer depends on your query patterns. If you have a lot of queries that aren't date-limited, they'll slow down as your table grows. Know this: all apps with growing databases, even yours, need to have their performance reviewed and optimized routinely. Once per calendar quarter is often wise, or more often if you're fortunate enough to have hypergrowth.